# LINQ query to find items where multiple substrings are searched on one column

Tags: linq

```
Select * from web_data where Title like "%Lawn%" || Title like "%silk%"......and so on.
```

Lawn, Silk etc are in `List<web_data>`. So i'm looking for a way to search those substrings in the `Title` column(`discription` property). One of them must be contained, then the row should be returned.

I've tried this

```
query = query
    .Where(x => filter.FabricType.Any(f => x.discription.Contains(x.discription)))
    .AsQueryable();
```

It's not working. That linq to sql code returns an error:

> Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.

any alternatives?

Comment: Tim Schmelter, I edited now u can help. :)

Comment: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: LINQ-to-SQL itself is your major impediment. Try Entity Framework. BTW, I think `Contains(x.discription)` should be `Contains(f.discription)`. (Or `description`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Contains()` or You can also use `.StartsWith()` or `.EndsWith().`

```
collListItem.Where(x => x.discription.Contains("Lawn") || x.discription.Contains("silk")).ToList();
```